# Running a single RSpec spec fails with "`require': cannot load such file"

Tags: ruby, macos, rspec

I am trying to get test-first-ruby-master as instructed but I am getting multiple errors. This is the structure of the files/directory in test-first-ruby-master:

```
Gemfile     Gemfile.lock    README.md   lib     spec
```

`lib` contains ruby files and `spec` contains spec files. 
I am trying to execute `00_hello_spec.rb` file on my terminal but it doesn't work.

**What I have tried**

1. `require "lib/00_hello.rb"`
2. `require_relative "lib/00_hello.rb"`

**Errors I get**

```
supritkumars-MacBook-Pro:test-first-ruby-master supritkumarshah$ rspec spec/00_hello_spec.rb 
/Users/supritkumarshah/Desktop/test-first-ruby-master/spec/00_hello_spec.rb:103:in `require': cannot load such file -- lib/00_hello.rb (LoadError)
    from /Users/supritkumarshah/Desktop/test-first-ruby-master/spec/00_hello_spec.rb:103:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/supritkumarshah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1226:in `load'
    from /Users/supritkumarshah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1226:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/supritkumarshah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1224:in `each'
    from /Users/supritkumarshah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1224:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/supritkumarshah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:97:in `setup'
    from /Users/supritkumarshah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in `run'
    from /Users/supritkumarshah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
    from /Users/supritkumarshah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
    from /Users/supritkumarshah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/supritkumarshah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /Users/supritkumarshah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/supritkumarshah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/supritkumarshah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The `require` is failing because you're requiring a relative path, `'lib/00_hello.rb'`, but the directory it's relative to (the root of your project) is not in the list of directories that Ruby is looking in for files to `require` (the load path, `$LOAD_PATH`).

There are lots of ways to fix this. Here are some:

- Tell rspec to add the root of your project to the load path. Since that's your current directory, you can use `.`:

  ```
  rspec -I. spec/00_hello_spec.rb
  ```
- Change your spec to `require_relative '../lib/00_hello'`. This works regardless of the current directory or load path — a good idea in command-line programs, although not so important for a learning project.
- As B Seven answered, change your spec to `require './lib/00_hello'`. This requires you to run rspec in the root of your project.
- You can even remove the `require` altogether! When you run rspec, if the current directory has subdirectories named `lib` and/or `spec`, rspec adds them to the load path. This also requires you to run rspec in the root of your project. This solution won't work if you need the `require` when running your program for real (not under rspec).

Note that including the `.rb` in the filename you `require`d did not cause the problem, but it's not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Although Dave's answer is correct, I prefer to use:

```
require './lib/00_hello'
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried adding `require 'bundler/setup'` at the top of your test helper file?